# MysqlDataReader - Getting unsigned byte column?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a code that simply gets an unsigned byte from a column's value in Mysql.

```
MySqlDataReader reader = MasterServer.Instance.Sql_Connection.Reader;
reader.Read();
sbyte slot = (sbyte)reader.GetByte("slot");
```

And my column's "slot" in the table is TINYINT(3) and marked as signed.

However, the code returns 0, as it should return -1 (There's -1 in that column for the test).
Why's that? Thanks!

**C#**

Comment: I haven't used MySql, but does method reader.GetByte() support signed bytes? Does this work? sbyte slot = (sbyte)reader["slot"];

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest and depending on the index of the column it should be `GetByte(column,...)`

```
sbyte slot = (sbyte)reader.GetBytes(0,0,null,0);
```

This is if the sql statement looks as following: `SELECT slot FROM table` therefore `GetBytes(0,...)`.

SqlDataReader has a [GetByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbyte%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function